# Does Crashlytics Beta have a way to export all *new* UDIDs?

Tags: crashlytics, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-beta

I'm using Crashlytics Beta to distribute apps for testing. Every time someone signs up with a new device, I get an email with their UDID. It's tedious to add 100 UDIDs one by one. Is there a way to export all UDIDs that aren't already on my provisioning profile?

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried looking in Fabric.app for these?

Comment: I looked but couldn't find a way to export all. I double-checked I have the latest Fabric.app too (currently 2.6.17)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Crashlytics does not provide a built-in mechanism for exporting all UDIDs.

In the meantime, I wrote a Python script that will merge UDID files into a single file for upload to the Apple Developer Portal. To collect the UDID files I make the assumption that you grab them all at once from an email client, but perhaps someone could write a filter that collects them over a period of time. So far, this is the easiest solution I've come up with.

Merge UDID Files: https://github.com/jarrodparkes/merge-udid-files

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. When distributing the next build that has a tester whose UDID we now have, but didn't previously, there is a way to get all UDIDs from the Fabric macOS app. When doing your next distribution, after selecting the testers, there should be a .csv file present with the UDIDs needed for your testers.